# Разбить список на парные элементы

Tags: python

```
ListWithCortege = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1)]
for item in ListWithCortege:
    print(item)
    for element in item[0:2]:
        print(element)
dict = {
(2,4):'1',
(4,2):'2',
(2,1):'3',
(1,0):'4',
(1,1):'5',
(4,1):'6'
}
```

### Вывод:

```
(2, 4, 2, 1, 0)
2
4
(4, 2, 1, 0)
4
2
(1, 1, 0)
1
1
(4, 1)
4
1
(1, 4, 1)
1
4
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как из элементов кортежа получить поочередные пары чисел?
`[((2,4),(4,2),(2,1),(1,0)), ((4,2),(2,1),(1,0)), ((1,1),(1,0)), (4,1), ((1,4),(4,1)) )]`
и можно ли их потом сравнить со значениями ключей словаря?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `zip`:

```
ListWithCortege = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1)]

result = []
for cort in ListWithCortege:
    result.append(tuple(zip(cort, cort[1:])))

print(result)
```

**UPD** (работает если окажется, что в списке число

```
for cort in ListWithCortege:
    try:
        result.append(tuple(zip(cort, cort[1:])))
    except TypeError:
        result.append(tuple([cort])) # тут напишите действия, которые нужно сделать, если элемент один.
```

**UPD 2** работает с одноэлементным кортежом, добавляя парное значение:

```
for cort in ListWithCortege:
    if len(cort)==1:
        result.append(tuple((cort[0], -1)))
    else:
        result.append(tuple(zip(cort, cort[1:])))
```

Comment: а если изменить список вот так? `ListWithCortege = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1)]` то как тогда?

Comment: @Nommad зависит от того, что вы хотите в ответе на это .

Comment: `ListWithCortege = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1,)]`  если например последний элемент кортежа состоит из одного элемента (с запятой, нужно именно так), можно как-то дописать проверку, если элемент один, то к нему добавляется число? потому что в ответе, который дали вы, при таком условии получается ошибка

Comment: @Nommad дополнил ответ